# Comments migrated to chat are assigned a new timestamp, rather than preserve the original timestamp

Tags: feature-request, chat, timestamps, move-to-chat

I'm betting it's intentional for some technical reason, but when you migrate messages from comments to chat, the timestamps are lost and the new chat messages are assigned new timestamps, the time of the migrate.

It's not really a big issue for regular users, but if a mod tries to combine rooms with the chat message migration feature, you can easily get out-of-order messages. It would be better if migrated chat messages were timestamped based on the original publishing as a comment.

Comment: The issue is going to be a bit more complex than this, and probably has no easy/reasonable solution. Chat messages are assigned a message ID when created, which is a sequential integer. They are also assigned a timestamp. Most of what I've seen of chat bases actions on the message ID, rather than the timestamp of the message. The chat system makes the assumption that message IDs are *always* in time-order, with newer messages having larger message IDs. It would likely be a *lot* of work to make it such that there was nowhere which made that assumption.

Comment: @Makyen Hmmm, you're probably right. The messages just load in order from the table. Having a user option to re-order them can't be that hard. Get time stamps, re-order, populate.

Comment: Wow, are there really 58 million SE chat messages? The number of the current chat ids?

Comment: There are a bit more than double that. You need to look on chat.SE, chat.SO, and chat.MSE. The three domains use different databases, so have different message ID sequences. There are about 58.8M on chat.SE, 52.8M on chat.SO, and 8.97M on chat.MSE.

Comment: Quite the treasure trove of trivial tripe :)